# What's the best generic/automated approach to create objects (domain models) for integration tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, automated-tests, integration-testing

I would like to create easily maintanable integration tests for multilayered application, but I have ran into a problem of **finding a flexible approach for creating my objects**. Additionally, I would like to preserve a possibility to sometimes control objects creation.

In my tests I create my objects (domain models), persist them in the database, retrieve the objects filtered by domain logic in the response from my odata controllers, serialize them back to my domain models, and compare them against what was expected to be returned.

What I have tried so far was using Specflow's data tables in my scenarios combined with FizzWare NBuilder, however I can already see that maintaining the tests would not be convinient, as any minor changes in the domain model could result in the necessity to update multiple areas of the integrational tests project (in this case NBuilder objects configuration and each specflow scenario where data for changed model is provided), because the domain model and logic of my application are complex.

Is there any generic, automated approach to achieve this?

**Please** share your knowledge/experience on this matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would write a comment but my reputation doesn't allow me to do that.

Give a look at Autofixture library. It's an open source library created by Mark Seemann that provides a way to automatically create objects with fake data for testing purposes:

https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture

here's a very simplistic example

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, Lastname);
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void FullNameProperlyResolved()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        var sut = fixture.Create<Person>();
        var expectedFullName = string.Format("{0} {1}", sut.FirstName, sut.Lastname); 
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedFullName, sut.FullName);
    }
}
```

Comment: why a comment? This seems like an appropriate answer.

Comment: Have you used autofixture yourself?not sure how it will be easier to describe business data using that framework. Please elaborate your answer eg with a few examples

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a simple example. I'm actually using it and it's very useful.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, however I would like to know 3 things. 1. Can I in any way control things like length of generated string or range of generated number using this framework? 2. Can I cast generated objects to my domain models with no problem? (to compare the data received from my data services against the generated objects) 3. Does this framework work properly with types which have circular references?

Comment: I just tweeted the question to Mark Seemann who created Autofixture. He will be able to give you a much more complete answer :-)

Comment: @AndrewB 1. Yes. 2. The object generated are of the types you ask for. Why do you need to cast them? 3. No.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought they were wrapped into some other type. I will give it a try and mark your comment as answer if it works out well for me.